# Python3 Gtk3 : D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: Failed to open "/etc/machine-id"

Tags: python, linux, gtk, gtk3, dbus

I am trying to write Python3 code with Gtk3, in SLES11 linux machine

I get this error:

> D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine
> uuid: Failed to open "/etc/machine-id"

the /etc/machine-id not present in my machine, but I can't have permissions to generate that using "dbus-uuidgen"

Is there any option to override that in the python code itself or in some env variable ?

Thanks
Oren

Answer (score 1):

No, having `/etc/machine-id` set is a requirement of D-Bus being installed. It looks like D-Bus was not installed correctly. You should be able to run `dbus-uuidgen --ensure` as root (or using `sudo`). If you don’t have root access, you cannot fix this situation and you should get in touch with your system administrator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't have admin permission but I will check.